# A topological space whose closed subsets are locally connected

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact $T_0$ topological space such that every closed subset of $X$ is locally connected. Is there any characterization for such a space? I guess $X$ is Noetherian, but I cannot prove that. Any hint is appreciated.

Recall that a topological space $X$ is called *Noetherian* if any ascending chain of open
subsets stabilizes after finitely many steps, equivalently, any non-empty set of closed subsets
of $X$, ordered by inclusion, has a minimal element.

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate at mse. Incidentally, such spaces need not be Noetherian: consider for example the topology on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ consisting of all upwards-closed sets. Every closed set in this topology is connected, and every open cover has a singleton subcover. (Even better, consider the cofinite topology on any infinite set - this is additionally $T_1$.)

Comment: And trivially there are no $T_2$ examples with more than one point.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, cofinite is Noeterian.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, cocountable is not compact (sorry to bother you about trivialities).

Comment: @WlodAA Welp, not my day.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, coronavirus is messing around but we are still ok. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ (Y\ S)\ $ be an arbitrary locally connected space. Let $\ Y\subset X\ $ -- **sharp** inclusion (not just $\, \subseteq).\ $ Define:

$$ T\ :=\ S\cup \{X\} $$

Then $\ (X\ T)\ $ is compact and every closed subset of $\ X\ $ is connected and locally connected.

Comment: You can use $\subsetneq$ `\subsetneq` for proper inclusion, to avoid needing a separate qualifier afterwards.

Comment: @LSpice, very nice, thank you. However, $\ \subsetneq\ $ is not aesthetic and it LOOKS ambiguous, it may be visually interpreted as "not contained": $\ Y\setminus X\ne\emptyset.\ $ (True, there is a special notation for this too but nevertheless...).